# Text in php table goes off page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html-table

I have a php table and a textarea in it. I insert the text from the mysql database. When the text is short is ok. But, when it is too long it goes off the page like that:

Do you know how I can fix that?

Here is my code:

```
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
                    <div style='min-height: 125px;'> Topic Title: ".$row['topic_title']."<br> by ".$row2['post_creator']. " - ".$row2['post_date']."<hr>".$row2['post_content']."
                    </div></td>

                    <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>Date & Time<br><br><hr><br> ".$row2['post_date']."</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'><hr></td>
                    </tr>";
                }
```